# How to prove such a hyperbolic sine cosine related equality?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\ln \left(\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^2 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)}{4}\right)=\text{arcsinh }(2)+2 \text{ arccsch }(2)$$

Comment: If you have/are taking integral calculus, try deriving all of the hyperbolic trig/inv trig functions from scratch. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ln \left(\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^2 \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)}{4}\right)=\ln\left(\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^2\left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)-\ln (4)$$

$$=\ln\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^2+\underbrace{\ln\left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)}_{=\,\text{arcsinh}\, 2}-\ln 4$$

$$=\ln\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^2}{4}+\underbrace{\ln\left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)}_{=\, \text{arcsinh} \,2}$$

Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function#Inverse_hyperbolic_sine)

$$=\underbrace{2\ln\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)}{2}}_{=\,2\,\text{arccsch}\, 2}+\underbrace{\ln\left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)}_{=\,\text{arcsinh} \,2}$$